# Unable to parse data from firebase in flutter

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the model I am using for the data.

[image]

Here is the Future I am using to extract the data.

```
Future<List<Topic>> getTopics(String subjectid) async {

    var ref = db.collection('topics')
                    .where(
                      'subject',
                      isEqualTo: subjectid
                    );
    
    var snapshot = await ref.get();
    var data = snapshot.docs.map((s) => s.data());
    var topics = data.map((d) => Topic.fromJson(d));
    
    return topics.toList();

}
```

Here is how I have the data in firebase.

[image]

I am getting a error in the type cast:

> type 'InternalLinkedHashMap<string, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>?

When I try to print the `topics.toList()`, the print returns nothing.

I played around with my model, made sure all the columns are mapped correctly. My call for another collection works fine. But this one just won't work.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)